# How to fold try/catch, switch, for, while and if statements in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

IntelliJ Idea fold if and other statements in JavaScript, but not in Java. How can I get this feature? Maybe you know some plugin or settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible from Code > Folding or using the icons from the left bar (collapse/expand), but you can do it in a harder way: manually.

E.g.:

- select the try block
- Code > Folding > Fold Selection / Remove Section ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Period</kbd>, where <kbd>Period</kbd> is the <kbd>.</kbd>)
- you'll see `...` instead of that block
- now that block also has the icons for collapse/expand on the left bar

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't know a better solution. If nobody can provide, you can click on Create Issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues and choose Feature from the right side.

Comment: Seems like that is best and only one solution

Comment: Thanks! add in mac it's `ctrl+shift+.`

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio, in order to fold a try/catch structure -

1. In the editor window, select the left brace after try
2. Type on keyboard <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Now the complete try { .. } block will be folded.

Comment: Same for `Clion`

Comment: The dot is the one in the main keyboard not numeric keypad.

Answer (score 1):

If I want to reduce  a try / catch section, it doesn't work for me on Intellij CI 2016, under Ubuntu 16.04 OS.

Even with shortcut or using menus.

Using menus Code > Folding > Fold Selection / Remove Section ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Period, where Period is the <kbd>.</kbd>), it'll close the entire function where the try/catch block is.

It doesn't work either if I use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Seems to be a conflict with other shortcut existing on the OS I'm running onto.

Comment: Nothing works for me on windows either.. I just inherited a black box project with some real spaghetti IF-ing going on! I cant believe such an established IDE lacks this fundamental feature for folding blocks!!! PHP storm and android studio have it and they are practically the same thing.

What were they thinking lol.

/END RANT. :D